# How to I create a sub contact group or a group container

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to programmably create a container in Contacts that holds any new groups I add (similar to "My contacts".  I don't know if this would be a group inside a group, or another container.

Comment: There is no feature of nested groups in Google Contacts so it isn't possible to create one via the API. If you want to manage a separate database of contacts using Google Apps Script then there are many different ways to do this, but you will never see the results in Google Contacts itself.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, neither the Contacts UI interface, the [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) nor [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app) allow you to create a group of contact groups.

You could use Apps Script as an organizational intermediary. For example, you could collect group names/ids into a Javascript object representation of a group container, and then use Apps Script functions to apply manipulations to contacts based on the group container name. Or you could also use the Contact's Notes field to hold a group container name/label -- the exact implementation would depend on your ultimate objective.

Regardless, you would not be able to get these group containers to appear in the Contacts UI.